# Should I use update with condition on database or query followed by update in application?

Tags: sql

I have a scenario that my application needs to update a record in postgresql database with a condition. The update is based on the table PK (`id`) and only if the status is not `active`.

I am thinking to send one SQL update statement to db like:

```sql
update table Table values(xxx) where id=xxx and status != 'active';
```

it should work but I have another thinking about scalibility on my database. I have one write instance and a few read instances. My application sends `update` to write instance and `query` to read instance, I have another solution:

```
const records = db.query("select * from Table xxx where id=xxx and status = active");
if (records.length === 0){
  return;
}
db.update(....)
```

In above code, it queries the record from db first, then do the update later. There are 90% chance that the record is active. So by doing that, it will stop updating the items by the first query. And query is hit on read instance which is on scale.

I wonder whether it is a good approach or not.

Comment: Which one DB instance is used, decided by which connection is used. If you connect to the write instance, all operations will send to it, regardless of read and write operation.

Comment: my application connects to different db instances based on operation. `query` goes to read, `update` goes to write.

Comment: I updated the question since it is a little confusing.

Comment: In a high concurrency scenario, due to database synchronization delays, the Update operation may be executed repeatedly.  But you exec update operation with where condition, so the operation is idempotent. You can determine whether the update operation was successful by the number of rows affected.

Comment: If I use `update with where`, it means all updates are sent to one write instance which is not scalable.

Comment: *I am thinking to send one SQL update statement to db like* Each DBMS have its own syntax. Do not try to imagine your own syntax - none server will accept it. [UPDATE in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) and [WITH in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), [UPDATE (with WITH) in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html). Both variants uses CTE in UPDATE statement by slightly different way - investigate.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only _one_ tag for the database product you are really using.